# Is it possible to use the mousepad powersource for a backlit keyboard?

Tags: usb, laptop, keyboard, motherboard, power-supply

I got a Lenovo laptop, its motherboard doesn't support backlit keyboards, there's no power jack to plug in the cable. But it does have a mousepad, which DOES have a place to power it.

Is it possible to  use the mousepad powersource for a backlit keyboard? Can I plug in the powercable into the mousepad slot?  Are there issues about the ***wattage, ampereage,*** or  ***voltage*?**

I realize this means the mouse-pad wont work anymore. And that a better solution would be to solder a power jack into the motherboard, or more realistically, some sort of extension cable which plugs into a USB slot. Of course. But those require customization. This won't.

Laptop is Lenovo G50-80. Backlit keyboard is for a Lenovo Z51-70. They are compatible. At worst, I'd be stuck with a keyboard without functioning lights....which is what I have now.

Please help me to improve this question if you  think it needs to.
There aren't any similar questions like mine, but please point me to one if you know of one.